# Data in text box from table

Tags: jquery, datatables

I try to generate table through jquery and then i concatenation mutiple columns into 1 single column . Then i hide these columns like

**UPDATE**

Generate table and after concatenate columns

```
if (re.length > 0) {

                        $("#services_schdulue").append
                        $('#services_schdulue thead').append(
                       "<tr><th>Service ID</th><th>Service Type</th><th>Service freq</th></tr>"
                           );

                        for (var i = 0; i < re.length; i++) {
                            if (re[i] !== null) {
                    $('#services_schdulue tbody').append('<tr><td>' + re[i][0] +
                        '</td><td>' + re[i][1] +
                         '</td><td>' + re[i][2] +''+re[i][3]+''+re[i][4]+
                         '</td></tr>');    
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

Then when data is display in table then i try to fetch data in textbox and in dropdown

like this

**UPDATE 2**

```
$(function () {
            debugger;
            $('#services_schdulue').on('click', 'tr', function () {
                $("#myModal").modal("show");
                var myTable = $('#services_schdulue').DataTable();
            var row = $(this);
            //$("#txt_serv").val($(this).closest('td').children()[0]);
            debugger;

            var serv = row.find('td')[1].firstChild.data;
            $("#txt_serv").val(serv);

            var rowDate = myTable.row(this).data();
            $("#txt_repeat").val(rowDate[2]);
            });
        });
```

Comment: Could you provide a sample of your data? You can use DataTable to hide your data for you and then you're looking at a much easier way of displaying the data in a modal.

Comment: sample data is already in screenshot @annoyingmouse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You JSFiddle was using `dataTable` which is the old way of initializing a DataTable. `DataTable` is much more powerful: This is how you could do it using arrays:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    example = $("#tabledata").DataTable({
        "dom": 'Blfrtip',
        "columns":[
            {
                "title":"No"
            },{
                "title":"Status"
            },{
                "title":"Speed"
            },{
                "title":"Reference",
                "sortable": false
            }
        ],
        "bSort": true,
        "scrollY": 100,
        "scrollX": true,
        "lengthMenu": [
            [10, 25, 50, -1],
            ['10 rows', '25 rows', '50 rows', 'Show all']
        ],
        "buttons": [
            'excelHtml5'
        ]
    });
    for(var i = 0; i < 400; i++){
        var speed = (1000 - (i * 2));
        example.row.add( ["abc", "def", speed, "sd"])
    }
    example.draw();
    $('#tabledata').on('click', 'tbody tr', function () {
        var rowData =  example.row(this).data();
        console.log(rowData);
        $("#myModal").modal("show");
        $("#txt_status").val(rowData[1]);
        $("#txt_speed").val(rowData[2]);
    });         
});
```

Though my preference would be to use objects:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var example = $("#tabledata").DataTable({
        "dom": 'Blfrtip',
        "columns":[
            {
                "title":"No",
                "data": "no"
            },{
                "title":"Status",
                "data": "status"
            },{
                "title":"Speed",
                "data": "speed"
            },{
                "title":"Reference",
                "sortable": false,
                "data": "reference"
            }
        ],
        "bSort": true,
        "scrollY": 100,
        "scrollX": true,
        "lengthMenu": [
            [10, 25, 50, -1],
            ['10 rows', '25 rows', '50 rows', 'Show all']
        ],
        "buttons": [
            'excelHtml5'
        ]
    });
    for(var i = 0; i < 400; i++){
        var speed = (1000 - (i * 2));
        example.row.add( {
            "no": "abc",
            "status": "def",
            "speed": speed,
            "reference": "sd"
        })
    }
    example.draw();
    $('#tabledata').on('click', 'tbody tr', function () {
        var rowData =  example.row(this).data();
        console.log(rowData);
        $("#myModal").modal("show");
        $("#txt_status").val(rowData.status);
        $("#txt_speed").val(rowData.speed);
    });         
});
```

You've got DataTables so you might as well make it work for you as much as possible.

So if you want to concatenate data within cells you can use a render like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var example = $("#tabledata").DataTable({
        "dom": 'Blfrtip',
        "columns":[
            {
                "title":"No",
                "data": "no"
            },{
                "title":"Status",
                "data": "status",
                "visible": false
            },{
                "title":"Speed",
                "data": "speed",
                "render": function(data, type, row){
                    return row.status + data;
                }
            },{
                "title":"Reference",
                "sortable": false,
                "data": "reference"
            }
        ],
        "bSort": true,
        "scrollY": 100,
        "scrollX": true,
        "lengthMenu": [
            [10, 25, 50, -1],
            ['10 rows', '25 rows', '50 rows', 'Show all']
        ],
        "buttons": [
            'excelHtml5'
        ]
    });
    for(var i = 0; i < 400; i++){
        var speed = (1000 - (i * 2));
        example.row.add( {
            "no": "abc",
            "status": "def",
            "speed": speed,
            "reference": "sd"
        })
    }
    example.draw();
    $('#tabledata').on('click', 'tbody tr', function () {
        var rowData =  example.row(this).data();
        $("#myModal").modal("show");
        $("#txt_status").val(rowData.status);
        $("#txt_speed").val(rowData.speed);
    });         
});
```

That way you still have the data in `rowData` to display within your modal.

Hope that helps. Working JSFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/wtnwgz09/26/).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access the data you can add an event listener to the tr click event. You were very nearly there but you needed to interrogate the DataTable for the data.

```
$('#services_schdulue tbody').on('click', 'tr', function (e) {
    console.log( myTable.row( this ).data() );
});
```

Working JSFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/annoyingmouse/yao0v4gb/) with your data.

Comment: i check js fiddle but td data not access in text box box or somewhere ? and i want to access this data in text box..

Comment: Did you have a console open? The data from the table is visible as an array, the example linked gives `["4", "Check", "", "6", "months(s)", "1000"]` when the row is clicked - I'm not sure what sort of modal you're using so I can't replicate your mechanism for pre-populating the data. If you change the function to `var rowDate = myTable.row( this ).data();`, then you can access the fields by the index., so `$("#txt_serv").val(rowDate[1]);`, etc.

Comment: check my update concatenate data also i try this what you said but display whole valye 6 month(s)1000 in txt_repeat textbox where i want to display these value separately

Comment: ["7", "Check transmission fluid", "2month(s)200", "2014-04-02 12:00:00", "2015-02-11 12:00:001000", "1day(s)"]   where as i want to split this data 2month(s)200

Comment: Goodness me, your question has changed! My solution will not work because the data has now changed - to do what you want isn't a DataTable issue anymore but a regex thing... either return your question to the way it was or start afresh.

Comment: no no ... i only concentrate columns some other way rest are the same.. but the solution you post i try this but not works..

Comment: no no ... i only concatenate  columns some other way rest are the same.. but the solution you post i try this but not works.

Comment: I really do think you need to get a JSFiddle up and running in order to illustrate what your data looks like and the libraries you're using - you seem to be getting into something of a tizzy because you're trying things and the altering them as you work. Please think about doing that and helping us to help you.

Comment: ok this is https://jsfiddle.net/wtnwgz09/18/ so in this demo data i want to merge status and speed column and give header " infor"

 and data in td column will be like this "def 1000" so after hiding status and speed columns .. 
only 

NO    infor  refrence 
column will be visible.. 

so after this when i click on row then pop up is appear with textbox Status and Speed 
so how i fetch hidden columns data in these text box